# i want to redirect any url to www

Tags: apache, web, url, redirect

Hi i have problem with i want to redirect any website to be **`https://www.something.com/en/`** i did that but if anyone write **`https://something.com/en/`** it's not redirecting to   **`https://www.something.com/en/`** i need to redirect any one if write **`https://something.com/en/`** to **`https://www.something/en/`** .

***my apache conf file :***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName something.com
      ServerAlias www.something.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/something.com/public
      Redirect permanent / https://www.something.com

</VirtualHost>
```

***.htaccess file :***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> and i tried this too :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *.something.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.something.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: HTTPS is on 443 port usually

Comment: @Kosh i know that ok did you mean i should to change https which i wrote in `<VirtualHost *:80>` to be http not https ? i did but  no any changes happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.something.com
    ServerAlias something.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.something.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =something.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.something.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=301]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.something.com
    ServerAlias something.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/something.com/public

    # Here goes your SSL keys and options:
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/www.something.com/cert.pem
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/www.something.com/privkey.pem
    #Include /etc/ssl/options-ssl-apache.conf
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/www.something.com/chain.pem

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =something.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.something.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```